# Stuck with NimbusSanL instead of Arial/Helvetica

Tags: fonts, ubuntu

For an article I need to use Times for the text body and Arial or Helvetica for section headings. I use Latex on Ubuntu. I've looked for ways of getting Arial/Helvetica to work, but I keep getting NimbusSanL in the document. I installed msttcorefonts and I can see them with `fc-list | grep -i arial`:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Italic.ttf: 
...
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ariali.ttf:
```

In the document I have:

```
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
```

But I'm still getting "NimbusSanL-Regu" when I check with `pdffonts`. How can I get the Arial or Helvetical font to work? The publisher keeps returning my document...

Would be grateful for any hints!
Ed

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,x11names,pdf]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Times
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% Arial/Helvetica
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}  
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Observation: With

```
\usepackage{lmodern} %Times
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% Arial/Helvetica
```

I'm getting NimbusSanL-Bold in pdffonts

With

```
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% Arial/Helvetica
\usepackage{lmodern} %Times
```

it's LMSans10-Bold.

System: ubuntu
Latex: latex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

Help would be very appreciated!

Ed.

Comment: Hi! You may increase your changes of getting a useful answer by providing a MWE illustrating your problem. I am not a Linux expert, but I am pretty sure any actual expert would also appreciate to know which LaTeX distribution and command line you use to compile your document.

Comment: BTW, use latex or pdflatex. With xelatex I keep getting an error.

Comment: The `lmodern` package loads the "Latin Modern" font family, *not* the "Times Roman" font family. If you need a Times Roman clone and need to use pdfLaTeX, load the `newtxtext` package. If you can use LuaLaTeX, simply load the `fontspec` package and issue the commands `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` and `\setsansfont{Helvetica Neue}`. If `Times New Roman` isn't available on your system, try `XITS` instead.

Comment: @Mico Thanx! Will try these hints too!

Comment: Do you have permission to redistribute Times or Arial embedded in your document? Afaicr, the idea of installing Nimbus etc. as substitutes was to avoid copyright issues.

Comment: @elford There is not usually any objection to embedding (a subset of) the font in a document and distributing the document. The issue is that you may not legally distribute *the fonts*. So they could not be made part of a package hosted on CTAN, for example, let alone included in a TeX distribution. Of course, this comment does not constitute legal advice and the OP should check. I have not looked at the licence for these fonts in particular. This is just a general comment based on my unqualified understanding of how these things usually go ;).

Comment: elfort, cfr: Hm. Thanks for bringing this up. This didn't occur to me. As cfr is saying, distributed is only the doc not the fonts, but indeed I guess I need to look into the licensing issue.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: If you are under the impression that `lmodern` gets you Times, try this before you do anything else:

- remove all font packages from your document;
- add the following lines to the preamble:

.

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
```

- send the file back and see what they say.

NimbusSans is a clone of Helvetica. Arial is another clone of Helvetica. NimbusRoman is a clone of Times.

`lmodern` loads the Latin Modern fonts in their default configuration i.e. Latin Modern Roman, Sans and Typewriter. If you load `helvet` first, Latin Modern Sans overwrites the effect. If you load it after, you get the font switch to NimbusSans (=Arial) but have done nothing about the serif fonts (i.e. that's still Latin Modern Roman). You don't want `lmodern` at all!

---

Otherwise...

You have a few choices. One is much less painful than the others. This is to switch to XeTeX or LuaTeX and use `fontspec` to select the fonts you need. Then you can use the system-installed `.ttf` fonts directly.

If that is not an option, you either need to convert the fonts to postscript type1 and create or find suitable support files (`.tfm`, `.fd`, `.map` etc.) or you can use the `.ttf` files directly if you can use pdfTeX. However, you still need the support files in that case.

Before you embark on any of this, you should get absolutely clear about why *exactly* the PDF is being returned to you. You want to know precisely what they are checking and what should be true that is not. Otherwise, you are going to spend time on a solution for nothing.

Ideally, the publisher will be able to advise you how to proceed in the case that you are using LaTeX. However, in this case, that sounds unlikely. But they must at least be able to tell you what tests they are running on the PDF and what the results should be.

Without knowing this, there is no guarantee that any of the solutions above will actually satisfy the publisher. The only relatively easy one is the first - XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX + `fontspec`. So if you want to try anything without more information, try that one. When you resend it, tell them that you need more details if the file still fails their tests.

The other possibilities are painful unless you already know the methods involved (in which case you wouldn't be asking) and can be time-consuming even if you do. Hence, these are not worth considering unless you are 100% certain that they are both necessary *and* sufficient to satisfy the publisher.

Comment: Hi cfr! Thank you for the answer. I already asked them how they check. Apparently, she's opening the document in PDF-XChange-Viewer and marking fragments of text to check the font. They require specific fonts for their "series", that's why they keep coming back to me that the font is still not the one they require. I tried this lualatex, but there is a bug in one of the articles that I can't find. The whole thing (it's a collection) compiles fine with latex and pdflatex though. This is the first time I'm doing this kind of editing.

Comment: With the change you suggested I'm getting NimbusRomNo9L-Regu and NimbusSanL-Bold. I already sent them different versions with this Nimbus font. That's what they keep sending back under the motto that "Helvetica or Arial is required for section headings". I think she literally wants to see "Arial" when she opens document properties in the PDF-XChange-Viewer... Maybe I should try the conversion as you're suggesting. I'll try to look up how to do it.

Comment: @user80201 If they will accept the document compiled with LuaTeX or XeTeX, use one of those. Finding the bug will be a *lot* easier than the alternatives.

Comment: @user80201 Incidentally, that is a bonkers way to check the font. Why do they care if they cannot see any visual difference? But it also matters whether they are requiring the fonts to be, say, truetype or type1 postscript or whatever.

Comment: @user80201 I don't think `otftotfm` is an option with those fonts as they will be too old. (For conversion.) You can use the simple `fontinst` method (but bear in mind it is only *relatively* simple. The first tutorial in the Font Installation Guide covers it, I think. You will need to produce `.afm` files from the `.ttf`. You can do this with `ttf2afm` and then feed `fontinst` the `.afm`s. If type1 is OK, you can convert. But, otherwise, you can just change the `.pfb` extensions to `ttf`. But finding the bug is likely easier.

Comment: Does she want Times or Times New Roman? See [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/times-new-roman-vs-urw-nimbus-roman-9l/174888). Somewhere, there is an idiot's guide to converting TNR for just this kind of case and I used it once before I knew anything at all about LaTeX's fonts. If it is still online somewhere.... I'm sure it used `ttf2tfm` for conversion which is not great, but neither are the fonts so I wouldn't worry. I can't find it, though.

Comment: @user80201 I can see if I can find anything if you can't figure something out. I've done this for TNR, probably. (I assume they want TNR.) I forget why I had to do it but it was some equally bonkers requirement. Note that there are a zillion different version of Times and TNR....

Comment: Ehem... not sure how to put is delicately in English, but this woman, the contact person, is herself not the best informed on matters font and doesn't really welcome "knowledge challenges" ;-) The impression I have is that she has a check-list that she just follows. She's finally accepted the LMRoman's that I managed to get into the doc, so now it's just the stupid Nimbus that she keeps rejecting. By now I found out that Nimbus is a good enough substitute. Never had a problem with Nimbus in conference submissions. Will try to fix doc for lualatex and google for instructions on coversion.

Comment: @user80201 Wait! She accepts Latin Modern Roman as a substitute for Times, but not NimbusSans as a substitute for Arial?!! Latin Modern really is not like Times at all... That's... that's.... Oh, my. In that case, though, I have an idea. It ought, I think, be possible to tell pdfTeX to *call* Nimbus-whatever by a different name. If it is *just* the name which is being checked... (I did think this would be evil, but if she's accepting LMR for TNR just because they both have 'Roman' in the name, then I don't think it is evil after all.) It might not work, mind....

Comment: As I was saying... I think she just checks what the software shows when she marks text. By now I've so had enough of this back and forth with them that I'd even go for a nasty hack... I have no clue about fonts myself, but it did sound like the LM fonts were not exactly TNR... Well, that got through somehow. Found website explaining conversion. Will try lualatex again tomorrow (it's 4AM here).

Comment: I followed your advice with lualatex but it's now getting stuck at pstricks with undefined control sequence \ifnum\pdfshellescape . I guess next step will be resorting to font conversion...

Comment: @user80201 See e.g. [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198627/) for inclusion of `pstricks` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

run it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman PS Std}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}  
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

the embedded fonts are

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
UIFWKX+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
IJBOSK+TimesNewRomanPSStd-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
VCCRKM+TimesNewRomanPSStd-Italic-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
```

If you do not have a copy of the Times New Roman use one of a Windows or Mac installation or search for a free download and then use

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
PHSWKH+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
YUBITE+TimesNRCyrMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
QIOIVK+TimesNRCyrMT-Inclined         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
```

Comment: thank you too for the hint! It's totally hopeless! I've been trying to switch to lualatex and now it's getting stuck at undefined \pdfshellescape. Both lualatex and xelatex. With -shell-escape on (I've googled that one already.) The shellescape must be from pstricks. That's where it stops. Found this tip https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/i6OAlG81-QQ but doesn't work in my case. Any ideas how to get past the shellescape?